# Expo fails to build

Tags: expo

I am running and expo project and it fails to build. When I run `expo-doctor`, I get the error `Check Expo config (app.json/ app.config.js) schema Unexpected error while running 'Check Expo config (app.json/ app.config.js) schema' check: FetchError: request to https://exp.host/--/api/v2/project/configuration/schema/50.0.0 failed, reason:`  anyone encountered this error before? How did you solve it?

Comment: The error message literally screams that the error is in app.json or app.config.js. Can you share that file as well?

Comment: The app.json has no problem